# Stream.pipe event 'end' triggers only once on Nodejs socket.io-stream

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, stream

I have a server and a client set up with nodejs. The server is sending a file to the client with socket.io-stream. When the file is transfered I want to start working with it on the client side. For that I am listening to the 'end' event of the stream. 
My code works but only once. On the first file I send the event is triggered, but not on the next ones. After the first file, the next ones are corrupted and are 0 Bytes.

server.js

```
 socketObj.emit('order', orderData);

 ss(socketObj).on('file', function(stream) {
            fs.createReadStream('./uploads/'+ orderData.file.name +'').pipe(stream);
 });
```

client.js

```
socket.on('order', function(data) {

    var stream = ss.createStream();

    ss(socket).emit('file', stream);

    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(data.file.name));

    stream.on('end', function(){
        doSomeStuff(data); //This function is called only once
    });

});
```

I've tried using 'end' and 'finish' events, setting autoClose as true and false, using stream.close() and stream.end(), but nothing works. For me is like something is not resetting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your client.js file:

```
socket.on('order', function(data) {

    var stream = ss.createStream();
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(data.file.name);

    ss(socket).emit('file', stream);

    stream.pipe(writeStream);

    writeStream.on('close', function(){
        doSomeStuff(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get the same behavior.